# What does the Makefile symbol $= mean?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I've searched the documentation for Make and online forums.  I've also searched the documentation for Bash.  Maybe I've missed something.

I have a makefile containing

```
BUILD_SYSTEM :=$= build/make/core
BUILD_SYSTEM_COMMON :=$= build/make/common
include $(BUILD_SYSTEM_COMMON)/core.mk
```

What doe the `$=` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what version of make you're using so I'll assume a standard POSIX-compliant version such as GNU make.

In makefiles, `$x` for any single character `x` means the expansion of a variable named `x`, with very few exceptions: `$$` expands to a single `$`, `$(` and `${` indicate the start of a variable name.  There may be a few other single characters that are special.

But other than those, any character can be a valid variable name.  So `$=` expands to the value of the variable `=`, just like `$a` expands to the value of the variable `a`.  This can be hard to set because simply using:

```
= = foo
```

won't work.  But you can hide the equal sign from the make parser by using another variable:

```
EQUAL = =
$(EQUAL) = foo
all: ; @echo $=
```

then:

```
$ make
foo
```

Comment: Yes, gnu-make.  I included the tag.